# JavaScript mortgage loan calculator returning "NaN" for monthly payment

Tags: javascript

I have been going insane over the last few days trying to figure this out, and I am at a complete loss as to what to do.

For an assignment I have to do for class, we have to analyse the following JavaScript code and correct the errors. I have managed to figure out most of it, but am stuck on this last part.

Whenever I click the "Calculate" button, it is returning `"$NaN.undefined"` for the monthly payment amount. I have gone over the code over and over again, and everything seems to match what it shows in my textbook, so I have no idea what I need to change to make it work properly.

I just started learning JavaScript a few days ago, so I am VERY new at this. Any help or guidance anyone could give me would be extremely appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" /> 
<title>Make10-1 Oakwood Mortgage</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--Hide from old browsers
var thisMsg="  ** See us for your auto loan financing needs!!! **  "
var beginPos=0
function scrollingMsg() {
   msgForm.scrollingMsg.value=thisMsg.substring(beginPos,thisMsg.length)+thisMsg.substring(0,beginPos)
   beginPos+=1
   if (beginPos > thisMsg.length) {
      beginPos=0
   }
   window.setTimeout("scrollingMsg()",200)
}

var salesAmt
var loanAmt
var loanRate
var loanYears

function valSaleDownAmt() {
    var salesAmt=parseInt(LoanCalc.SaleAmt.value,10)
    if (isNaN(salesAmt) || (salesAmt <=0)) {
        alert("The sales amount is not a valid number!")
        LoanCalc.SaleAmt.value = ""
        LoanCalc.SaleAmt.focus()
    }
    else {
        var DownPayment=parseFloat(LoanCalc.DownPmt.value)/100
        if (isNaN(DownPayment) || (DownPayment <= 0) || DownPayment > 100) {
           alert("The Down Payment Rate is not a valid number!")
           LoanCalc.DownPmt.value = " "
           LoanCalc.DownPmt.focus()
    }
        else {
            var amtDown = salesAmt*DownPayment
            var loanAmt = salesAmt-amtDown
            LoanCalc.LoanAmt.value = dollarFormat(loanAmt.toFixed(2))
            LoanCalc.Rate.focus()
        }
    }
}

function CalcLoanAmt() {
    loanRate=parseFloat(LoanCalc.Rate.value)
    if (isNaN(loanRate) || (loanRate <= 0)) {
        alert("The interest rate is not a valid number!")
        LoanCalc.Rate.value = ""
        LoanCalc.Rate.focus()
    }
    else {
        loanYears=parseInt(LoanCalc.Years.selectedIndex)
        if (isNaN(loanYears) || (loanYears < 1)) {
            alert("Please select a valid number of years from the list!")
            LoanCalc.Years.selectedIndex = "0"
            LoanCalc.Years.focus()
        }
        else {
        var monthlyPmt = monthly(loanAmt,loanRate,loanYears)
        LoanCalc.Payment.value=dollarFormat(monthlyPmt.toString())
        }
    }
}

function monthly(loanAmt,loanRate,loanYears) {
    var Irate = loanRate/1200
    var Pmts = loanYears*12
    var Amnt = loanAmt * (Irate / (1 - (1 / Math.pow(1+Irate,Pmts))))
    return Amnt.toFixed(2)
}

function dollarFormat(valuein) {
    var formatValue = ""
    var formatDollars = ""
    formatAmt = valuein.split(".",2)
    var dollars = formatAmt[0]
    var dollarLen = dollars.length
    if (dollarLen > 3) {
        while (dollarLen > 0) {
            tempDollars = dollars.substring(dollarLen - 3,dollarLen)
                if (tempDollars.length == 3) {
                    formatDollars = "," + tempDollars + formatDollars
                    dollarLen = dollarLen - 3
                } else {
                    formatDollars = tempDollars + formatDollars
                    dollarLen = 0
                }
            }
        if (formatDollars.substring(0,1) == ",")
            dollars = formatDollars.substring(1,formatDollars.length)
        else    
            dollars = formatDollars
        }
        var cents = formatAmt[1]
        var formatValue="$"+dollars+"."+cents
        return formatValue
    }

 function popUpAd() {
    open("make10-1notice.html","noticeWin","width=520,height=270")
 }

 function lastModified() {
    var lastModDate = document.lastModified
    var lastModDate = lastModDate.substring(0,10)
     displayDateLast.innerHTML="<span style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:9px; font-weight:bold'>This document was last modified "+lastModDate+"</span>"
 }

//-->
</script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
background-image: url(financial_symbol.jpg);
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body onload="scrollingMsg(); popUpAd(); lastModified()">
<div align="center">
<p align="center"><img src="make10-1banner.jpg" width="750" height="120" alt="banner" /></p>
<form id="msgForm" action="">
<p style="text-align:center"><input type="text" name="scrollingMsg" size="25" /></p>
</form>
</div>
<div style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
<h3 align="center">Home Loan Payment Calculator</h3>
<form id="LoanCalc" action="">
<table width="346" align="center" cellspacing="3">
    <tr>
       <td align="right">
          <span style="color:#cc0000">*</span>Sale Price:
       </td>
       <td><input type="text" name="SaleAmt" id="SaleAmt" size="9" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">
         <span style="color:#cc0000">*</span> Down Payment as a percent
      </td>
      <td><input name="DownPmt" type="text" id="DownPmt" size="4" onblur="valSaleDownAmt()" /> 
      %</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td align="right">
          <span style="color:#cc0000">*</span> Interest Rate (e.g. 5.9):
      </td>
       <td><input type="text" name="Rate" id="Rate" size="4" /> %  
       </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
       <td align="right">
          <span style="color:#cc0000">*</span> Select Number of Years:  
  </td>
       <td><select name="Years" id="Years">
         <option selected="selected">Select Years</option>
         <option value="10">10</option>
         <option value="15">15</option>
         <option value="20">20</option>
         <option value="25">25</option>
         <option value="30">30</option>
         <option value="40">40</option>
       </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td align="right">
         <input name="button" type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="CalcLoanAmt()" />
       </td>
       <td>
         <input name="Reset" type="reset" />
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">
         <span style="color:#cc0000">*</span> Loan Amount          
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="LoanAmt" type="text" id="LoanAmt" size="9" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td align="right">
          <span style="font-weight:bolder">Monthly Payment</span>: 
       </td>
       <td><input type="text" name="Payment" id="Payment" value=" " size="12" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p style="color:#cc0000; text-align:center">* Indicates a required field.</p>
</form>
</div>
<div id="displayDateLast" style="margin-left:5%">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @adeneo: Or she has decided to enjoy nice, clean, semicolon-free code.

Comment: @cookiemonster - crap, I didn't even think about that, but that's probably it. They do look ugly and we don't really need them

Comment: @adeneo: I do believe I mentioned that this is NOT my code, this was a code provided to me that I have to review for errors. The lack of semicolons was not my decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some changes in two of your functions, and rest of the functions and html are fine. And it worked, please check it:-

```
         function valSaleDownAmt() {
            var saleAmtInput = document.getElementById("SaleAmt"),
            salesAmt=parseInt(saleAmtInput.value,10),

            downPaymentInput = document.getElementById('DownPmt'),
            DownPayment=parseFloat(downPaymentInput.value)/100,
            loanRateInput = document.getElementById('Rate'),
            loanRate=parseFloat(loanRateInput.value),
            loanYearsInput = document.getElementById('Years'),
            loanYears=parseInt(loanYearsInput.value);

            if (isNaN(salesAmt) || (salesAmt <=0)) {
                alert("The sales amount is not a valid number!")
                saleAmtInput.value = ""
                saleAmtInput.focus()
            }
            else if (isNaN(DownPayment) || (DownPayment <= 0) || DownPayment > 100) {
                alert("The Down Payment Rate is not a valid number!")
                downPaymentInput.value = " "
                downPaymentInput.focus()
            } else   if (isNaN(loanRate) || (loanRate <= 0)) {
                alert("The interest rate is not a valid number!")
                loanRateInput.value = ""
                loanRateInput.focus()
            } else  if (isNaN(loanYears) || (loanYears < 1)) {
                alert("Please select a valid number of years from the list!")
            }
            else {
                CalcLoanAmt(salesAmt,DownPayment,loanRate,loanYears); 
            }
        }

        function CalcLoanAmt(salesAmt,DownPayment,loanRate,loanYears) {
            var amtDown = salesAmt*DownPayment,
            loanAmt = salesAmt-amtDown,
            monthlyPmt = monthly(loanAmt,loanRate,loanYears);
            document.getElementById('Payment').value=dollarFormat(monthlyPmt.toString());
            document.getElementById('LoanAmt').value = loanAmt;
        }
```

That means, no need of the global variables like:-

```
var salesAmt
var loanAmt
var loanRate
var loanYears
```

You can remove this variables.

And you have to modify in two places in your html:-

One is:-

```
     <tr>
         <td align="right">
             <span style="color:#cc0000">*</span> Down Payment as a percent
         </td>
         <td><input name="DownPmt" type="text" id="DownPmt" size="4" /> 
          %</td>
      </tr>
```

That means, you have to remove the function call on blur of the input box.

And the second is:-

```
   <tr>
      <td align="right">
         <input name="button" type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="valSaleDownAmt()" />
       </td>
        <td>
          <input name="Reset" type="reset" />
         </td>
   </tr>
```

That means you've to call the function valSaleDownAmt instead of  the function CalcLoanAmt, on click on the calculate button.

The functionality of the previous code was same, but that would raise some issue in certain case, so i think it is more proper code. Try it.

Comment: Ahhh, that worked. Thank you so much!!!!!!!! I could kiss you right now! You guys are all the best, thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Give a person a fish and they eat for a day, teach a person to fish and.. oh nevermind.

Comment: I really did attempt what you suggested, but again, I'm in an Intro class and just started all of this stuff a few days ago. When I tried to go through the debugger thing you suggested, I had NO idea what I was doing, couldn't figure it out, and was just getting even more confused and in even more over my head. I'm not just trying to get through the assignments, I AM trying to learn all of this stuff. Now I can compare what Indra had with what I had and see what I was missing.

Comment: I've made few changes in my code, you can try it. Though your problem was solved in the previous answer, but later I realized it could create an issue in certain situation. So, I made this change.

Answer (score 0):

A great opportunity to learn to use the debugger to step through your code. Add a couple of breakpoints in your functions that calculate the values and set a watch on the variables that are used to calculate the monthly payment and determine where they start returning an invalid value.  You'll find the offending code in no time :)

You can read about the debugger for Chrome at https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging. There is also a decent introductory video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htZAU7FM7GI.

Also, although not technically required, you should be ending your statements with a semi-colon.  If you don't know all of the various statement rules for Javascript, leaving out the semi-colons can have unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

I think Bill has the best "answer". But I think in this particular example, you've got `loanAmt` defined in 2 places (var loanAmt).

I think you don't want it defined in the 2nd place (the local variable).

When `CalcLoadAmount` calls `Monthly` right now, the value of `loadAmt" isn't defined. I tried removing the 2nd variable declaration, and it might be the fix you need....

```
function valSaleDownAmt() {
    var salesAmt=parseInt(LoanCalc.SaleAmt.value,10)
    if (isNaN(salesAmt) || (salesAmt <=0)) {
        alert("The sales amount is not a valid number!")
        LoanCalc.SaleAmt.value = ""
        LoanCalc.SaleAmt.focus()
    }
    else {
        var DownPayment=parseFloat(LoanCalc.DownPmt.value)/100
        if (isNaN(DownPayment) || (DownPayment <= 0) || DownPayment > 100) {
           alert("The Down Payment Rate is not a valid number!")
           LoanCalc.DownPmt.value = " "
           LoanCalc.DownPmt.focus()
    }
        else {
            var amtDown = salesAmt*DownPayment

            //
            // THIS IS THE LINE I CHANGED RIGHT BELOW THIS COMMENT**
            //
            loanAmt = salesAmt-amtDown
            LoanCalc.LoanAmt.value = dollarFormat(loanAmt.toFixed(2))
            LoanCalc.Rate.focus()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem arises because your values remain undefined throughout. At the top of your script where your variables are declared, there are no default values given. Try giving them default values of 0. You shouldn't get undefined anymore. This won't solve your problem entirely but it's a good start. Also you should try making the variables global by putting this before the variables. So for the variables at the top do 
    this.salesAmt = 0
    this.loanAmt = 0
    this.loanRate = 0
    this.loanYears = 0

and everywhere they appear in your code put this before them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with the loanAmt variable as Brad Parks mentioned (it won't let me comment).  If you add the below code to the beginning of the CalcLoanAmt(), the function will work.  Although there are probably better ways of doing this, this code will fix it.  Good luck!

```
loanAmt=parseInt(LoanCalc.SaleAmt.value,10) - (parseFloat(LoanCalc.DownPmt.value)/100)
```